# 503 (Service Unavailable) for MERN stack app deployed on heroku

Tags: heroku, production, mern

I have deployed my MERN stack app on heroku but now I am having a trouble while making a POST request to my backend through a form.

I have run the command `heroku logs --tail`

and I am getting the following errors

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=still-island-81891.herokuapp.com request_id=b151ea11-23e7-4677-a6d9-d8fd9a213098 fwd="47.30.225.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's a request timeout. Does you expect that request to take a lot of time, e.g. if it's processing a lot of data or doing something very complex?

Comment: It's just submitting a login form which does some validations

Comment: Are you authenticating to a local database? Consider adding some log statements to that view so your `heroku logs` will show more useful information. You can also try sending a request manually using `curl`, Postman, or similar (though you may run into a CSRF token doing that).

Comment: I am using mongodb Atlas and I have sent requests through postman and also when I am running my app on localhost it's working just fine

Comment: It's irrelevant that this works locally. But you've got it working through Postman on Heroku?

Comment: Not on heroku. Sorry I didn't mentioned that

Comment: It's showing "Application Error" when I send the request through the Postman

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?